# Change value of <p> in PartialView

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have PartialView with `<p>`

Here is code

```
  <p id="findings-date" class="blue-text">Test</p>
```

I load partialView into div via this js code

```
 $(document).on('click',
    '.findingval',
    function () {
        var findingval = $(this).text();
        var idvalue = $(this).siblings('.idvalue').text();
       $('#left-window').load('@Url.Action("Findings", "PatientDatabase")');

    });
```

I need to change value of `p` to `findingval`

I tried

`$('#findings-date').text(findingval);` but it not works.

After this I tried just to get value like this `$('#findings-date').text();`

But it's null. Why so?

Seems it try to get data when partialView not appended.

Full code of script

```
   $(document).on('click',
    '.findingval',
    function () {
        var findingval = $(this).text();
        var idvalue = $(this).siblings('.idvalue').text();
       $('#left-window').load('@Url.Action("Findings", "PatientDatabase")');
       var date = $('#findings-date').text();
      alert(date);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous. Use the complete callback so the new html is loaded before you try to access it

```
$('#left-window').load('@Url.Action("Findings", "PatientDatabase")', function(){
  // new html exists now
  $('#findings-date').text(findingval );
});
```