# Ajax/JQuery Multiple .load() Requests Not Including .wrap() Content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, load

I am not sure what would be the derivative cause of this, but I am looking to `call`/`.load()` a specific section of content from one page to another, and though I have been able to retrieve some of the content targeted, the function does not seem to adhere any `.wrap()` selectors with the call, which I have implemented as individual scripts, (exemplified below).

For example, here's the `.wrap()` function, (which is not being adhered when .load() is retrieved):

```
$("iframe.selectediframe").wrap("<div class='wraptoiframe'></div>");
```

And the `.load()` function(s), which retrieve the iframe content requested, but do not apply any designated `.wrap()` selectors (such as: `.wraptoiframe`) within ids: `#section(x)` targetted:

```
$('#embed-content1').load('https://URL1.com/ #section1');
$('#embed-content2').load('https://URL2.com/ #section2');
```

Then I've just implement the HTML as so:

```
<div id="embed-content"></div>
```

How can I force multiple `.load()` to include in its execution all that has been selected to `.wrap()`, but only call wrap functions once?

Comment: Just answered same scenario with load() here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47489416/1175966

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for the comment; however, can you explain how this could be possible in a scenario with multiple .load() functions? (Since I would only want to call the .wrap() function once.)

Comment: I have updated this question, to further display what I am inquiring.

Comment: Use a complete callback for each one. Ajax is asynchronous

Comment: @charlietfl Sounds good. I imagine this is the best, valid solution. Perhaps you would be able to write out how I would implement this in reference to the example code I've provided? Sorry for the additional request, but I want to make sure that I'm understanding your suggested solution clearly.

Comment: Exact same as the link in my first comment...one for each `load()`

Comment: @charlietfl Ok... But since I am loading both of these functions on one page, calling the .wrap() function twice, even as complete callback, is duplicating the function twice as well...

Comment: What I mean to say is the .wrap() function I am trying to apply to both of these .load() functions is the same, not different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a complete callback and look inside each of the containers for the element to wrap

```
function wrapIframe(){
   // "this" is the embed-content container that is being populated
   $(this).find("iframe.selectediframe").wrap("<div class='wraptoiframe'></div>");
}
// pass wrapIframe as reference for complete callback of load
$('#embed-content1').load('https://URL1.com/ #section1',wrapIframe);
$('#embed-content2').load('https://URL2.com/ #section2', wrapIframe);
```